# How to create a navigation menu around an image

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

I have a heart and I need to construct the menu around that heart on both sides I have over 27 menu items.
I need it to be mobile friendly. Please any help?

Comment: Please check the screenshot

Comment: You have to place all your items using `position: absolute; top: xx; left: xx`. It can't possibly be mobile friendly because I can't imagine having 27 menu items on my screen and attempting to click an individual one clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the transforms declarations of css to rotate the `<span>` of text.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

```
span#menu1 {
    -ms-transform: rotate(7deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(7deg);
}
```